# Modifying VirtualDOM with Real DOM element in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, canvas

I have a canvas object that is provided to me programmatically by a security library which I must display to the user.  I know when using React, I should never directly modify the DOM, so I'm wondering if there is a way to do this through the Virtual DOM.

I have no problem getting it into the needed component's state, but I'm just not sure what I should do with it at that point.

Is there a way to include a full Real DOM object in the render?

Comment: I think that can be achieved using refs : https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: It is not HTML, it is a DOM element as if I had used
`document.createElemement('canvas')`

Comment: You're right. Mirko's answer will work for you.